# i start new nulled gem project in ruby mine and have error

Tags: ruby, rubymine-7

on os x 10.9.5 i start new gem project in ruby mine

```
require "test/version"

module Test
  puts "123"
end
```

and have error

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/qwerty/Documents/ruby/test/lib/test.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/version (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/qwerty/Documents/ruby/test/lib/test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What are you doing to get that error?  Running tests?  Using it from another script?

Comment: As the error states, the "require 'test/version'" is giving you problems.

Comment: error display then i run program from ruby mine